# Can I raise an exception if a statement is False?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

```
try:
    content = my_function()
except:
    exit('Could not complete request.')
```

I want to modify the above code to check the value of `content` to see if it contains string. I thought of using `if 'stuff' in content:` or regular expressions, but I don't know how to fit it into the `try`; so that if the match is `False`, it raises the exception. Of course, I could always just add an `if` after that code, but is there a way to squeeze it in there?

Pseudocode:

```
try:
    content = my_function()
    if 'stuff' in content == False:
        # cause the exception to be raised
except:
    exit('Could not complete request.')
```

Comment: Yes you can. Refer the manual [raising-exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

Comment: You should not catch all exceptions like this. It will hide all the syntax and other programming errors and debugging will be a night mare. Specify the type (class) of exception you want to catch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To raise an exception, you need to use the `raise` keyword. I suggest you read some more about exceptions in the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). Assuming `my_function()` sometimes throws `IndexError`, use:

```
try:
    content = my_function()
    if 'stuff' not in content:
        raise ValueError('stuff is not in content')
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    exit('Could not complete request.')
```

Also, you should **never** use just `except` as it will catch more than you intend. It will, for example, catch `MemoryError`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`. It will make your program harder to kill (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't do what it's supposed to), error prone on low-memory conditions, and `sys.exit()` won't work as intended.

**UPDATE:** You should also not catch just `Exception` but a more specific type of exception. `SyntaxError` also inherits from `Exception`. That means that any syntax errors you have in your files will be caught and not reported properly.

Comment: Catching `Exception` is equal to catching (almost) anything. `Exception` is the base class of most internal and all user defined exceptions.

Comment: In recent versions (> 2.5) `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` actually inherit from `BaseException` so they won't be caught. But I agree that it's usually best not to cast such a wide net.

Comment: Forgot about `SyntaxError`. You're right, this is still not good enough.

Answer (score 9):

```
try:
    content = my_function()
    if 'stuff' not in content:
        raise ValueError('stuff not in content')

    content2 = my_function2()
    if 'stuff2' not in content2:
        raise ValueError('stuff2 not in content2')

except ValueError, e:
    exit(str(e))
```

If your code can have several possible exceptions, you can define each with a specific value. Catching it and exiting will then use this error value.

Answer (score 5):

A nicer way to do this would be just to assert that the key is there:

```
assert 'stuff' in content, 'Stuff not in content'
```

If the assertion is not true, an `AssertionError` will be raised with the given message.

Comment: `assert` is a bad way of doing this since the user can disable any and all `assert`s by starting python with -O as parameter.

Comment: I find this useful to use in data analysis notebooks to check if calculations are as expected. It's an easy, clean, one liner and the code wont be run with `-O`

Answer (score 3):

You can raise an exception with `raise` if that's what you're asking:

```
if 'stuff' not in content:
    raise ValueError("stuff isn't there")
```

Note that you need to decide what kind of exception to raise.  Here I raised ValueError.  Likewise, you shouldn't use a bare `except`, but should use `except ValueError` or the like, to catch only the type of error you want to handle.  In fact, in this case that's especially important.  You presumably want to distinguish between a real error raised by `my_function` and the "stuff not in content" condition that you're testing.